# Generalization of Well Ordering principle from naturals to integers

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am currently reading the book "How to think like a Mathematician" and i came cross to part (b) of question (v) of exercise 28.19.
[image]

Here I think statement is false.
Counterexample: Suppose a subset of integers X s.t $$X =\{x\in\mathbb Z\vert x\le 0\}$$
Now X has no smallest element so this provides a counterexample.
But If i am not taking infinitely many negatives, then the principle is true. So the answer of the question is false ? Or I have to generalized it in another way? Thank you.
Note: Above X is set, sorry i was not able to type curly braces even i tried alot too.

Comment: "But If i am not taking infinitely many negatives" - this is irrelevant, since you need to consider *every* non-empty set of integers, in particular sets of infinite cardinality.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh, so i am going in correct way? I thought maybe " if a∈ ℤ, then {x ≥ a : x ∈ ℤ}" gives generalization. But found above counterexample.

Comment: Your counterexample is good.  Type `\{` to get a brace

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Got it Thanks. Yes i tried this but don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering well-ordering, the most concerning cases are infinite sets. If you had say a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, then there is a minimal element, but this is not a result of well-ordering.

Specifically, we can think of well-ordering as guaranteeing any *nonempty* set in general contains a minimal element, which is not true in $\mathbb{Z}$ by your own example.